# Laravel Dusk Test Multi Threading

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I have a series of `Laravel Dusk` tests as shown below ,,

[image]

when I run `php laravel dusk`
each of them work correctly but one test after another

how can I run more than one test in the same time each test in separate browser ??

and how to control the order of the tests to run ?

here is my `DuskTestCase` options :

```
 protected function driver()
    {
        $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--window-size=1920,1080',
        ]);


        return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            'http://localhost:9515',
            DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
                ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY,
                $options
            ),
            90000,
            90000
        );
    }
```

Comment: do you have multi thread version of php ?

Comment: I have PHP 7.4.6 ..

Comment: can you add some code?

Comment: i've edited the question and added some details ,, but the question is not related to specific test code it's about the way laravel dusk work and the options  I think !

Comment: look at this article i hope it helps. https://medium.com/@radicalloop/running-multiple-processes-asynchronously-with-php-laravel-15f84aba5abc